# How to know if a task was cancelled or the wait period is over

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

In a particular business scenario, there are multiple tasks running in parallel. I am using `CancellationToken` to cancel these tasks whenever the end user wishes. 
I also need to restart all the tasks after they have run for a particular period of time, lets say 3 hours. For this, I use:

```
_cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromHours(3))
```

This works fine. However, when 3 hours is up, the tasks automatically cancel and come out. Hence I am unable to detect the two scenarios separately viz: Was the cancellation due to user wanting to cancel or because 3 hours was up.

I am aware we can use a `Datetime` variable containing the last run time and push this inside our task. We can then terminate the task based on the current time difference and the last time it ran. But I was more looking at ways how TPL can help solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way by using only TPL. I made a workaround using System.Timers.Timer, here is my example:

```
 public static void DifferencingCancelAfterAndCancel()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("To cancel task press 'q': " + i);
            }
        }, token);

        task.Start();

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!task.IsCanceled)
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled by timer!");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Task has already been cancelled by user");
        };

        timer.Enabled = true;

        var k = Console.ReadLine();
        if (k == "q")
        {
            if (!task.IsCanceled)
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled by user!");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Task has already been cancelled by timer");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

You declare a timer that will elapse in 10 seconds. After that time **Elapsed event** will trigger the lambda function and you can put your logic there. The other way to cancel the task is when the user taps **'q'**, and you can put some other logic there.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Surely when you cancel in response to user input you can set a flag in the UI event handler?

This will not be set by a timeout and thus you might distinguish them.

If the UI allows cancellation of individual jobs then you might expose a flag as a property on each job context.